# handling return values in promises nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nodegit, node-github

I have built this function in NodeJs,

```
var Git = require('nodegit');
var fse = require('fs-extra');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var repoPath = 'D:\\sample'

function gitCommitHistory(repoPath, callbackGitCommitHistory) {
try {
    var open = Git.Repository.open;
    var commitList = [];
    open(repoPath)
      .then(function(repo) {              
        return repo.getMasterCommit();
      })
      .then(function(firstCommitOnMaster) {
        var history = firstCommitOnMaster.history();            
        history.on("commit", function(commit) {
            if (commit === 'undefined') {
                callbackGitCommitHistory(null, commitList);
            }
          var author = commit.author();
          commitList.push({commitAuthor:author.name(),commitAuthorEmail:author.email(), 
              commitMessage:commit.message(), commitSha:commit.sha(), commitDate:commit.date()});
        });
        history.on("error", function(err){
            console.log(err)
        })
        history.on("end", function(){               
            callbackGitCommitHistory(null, commitList);
        });
        history.start();
      });   
} catch (error) {
    callbackGitCommitHistory(error);
}
```

};

I have built this function using module "Nodegit". They are using promises as the callback handler.

In the function I am retrieving all the commits Done by a user on a repository and sending it as a response to the calling webservice.

The function works fine if there is atleast one commit, (i.e) the repo.getMasterCommit returns the commit history. But if I give the repoPath to a  new repo with zero commits then, nothing is returned from that function, hence i cannot send any response to the calling web service. Pls help on how to handle this situation!!!!!!!!

Comment: I dont see that you are catching the `error` or empty response from the `getMasterCommit`. You should do that check and i assume you continue to `callbackGitCommitHistory(error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Related issue](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/667) on GitHub repo.

That should be fixed in the next release (0.5) and is currently fixed in master via [661](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/pull/661). Ahmad Assaf is correct though, it was rejecting the promise chain since there's no head commit.